# limit length of each GROUP_CONCAT values

Tags: mysql

If I have per example the following table

```
cliente.nome
peter sampras
john mark
monalisa
```

the result with

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cliente.nome ORDER BY cliente.nome SEPARATOR ', ') as client
```

will be:

```
peter sampras,john mark,monalisa
```

Is possible to limit the length of each item so the result is:

```
pete,john,mona
```

Comment: See SUBSTRING_INDEX()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `SUBSTRING` or `LEFT` in your `GROUP_CONCAT` call -- I prefer using LEFT for this:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT LEFT(cliente.nome,4))
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d21f/1)

Comment: @metRo_ -- this might help -- it will add '...' after any name longer than 4 chars.  Best of luck! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9854/1

Answer (score 0):

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT SUBSTRING(cliente.nome,1,4))
```